# Correct initialize signaling thread webrtc under linux for message processing from other threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, webrtc

I'm newbie to webrtc, and there is no good documentation to about webrtc multithreading model.

My application have to communicate through janus-client,
I have one but only under windows, here is the reference
https://github.com/ouxianghui/janus-client

I have changed some class for make it compilable and working under linux, it's work correct. In application part there is signaling thread initialization with socket, and registering couple of threads for correct work of janus library. See below

Here I show main_qt.cpp , it's usual main with windows intialization, it work correct. I removed headers, for decreasing size, main is what interesting.
This four lines was commented, to work with linux.

```
rtc::WinsockInitializer winsockInit;
rtc::Win32SocketServer w32ss;
rtc::Win32Thread w32Thread(&w32ss);
rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->SetCurrentThread(&w32Thread);



static void registerMetaTypes()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<std::function<void()>>("std::function<void()>");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<std::string>>("std::vector<std::string>");

    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("int64_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("uint64_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("int32_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("uint32_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<vi::Participant>>("std::shared_ptr<vi::Participant>");
    qRegisterMetaType<rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::MediaStreamInterface>>("rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackInterface>");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<vi::CreateRoomResult>>("std::shared_ptr<vi::CreateRoomResult>");
}

static void initOpenGL() {
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(3, 2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vi::Logger::init();

    rtc::WinsockInitializer winsockInit;
    rtc::Win32SocketServer w32ss;
    rtc::Win32Thread w32Thread(&w32ss);
    rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->SetCurrentThread(&w32Thread);


    appDelegate->init();

    registerMetaTypes();

    rtc::InitializeSSL();

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    initOpenGL();

    int ret = 0;

    auto jcDialog = std::make_shared<JanusConnectionDialog>(nullptr);
    jcDialog->init();

    if (QDialog::Accepted == jcDialog->exec()) {
        jcDialog->cleanup();

        std::shared_ptr<GUI> w = std::make_shared<GUI>();
        appDelegate->getRtcEngine()->registerEventHandler(w);

        w->show();

        w->init();

        ret = a.exec();
    }

    appDelegate->destroy();

    rtc::CleanupSSL();

    return ret;

}
```

After win object initialization, it calls an initialization of appDelegate , function described bellow
appDelegate->init(); just singletone

```
void AppDelegate::init()
{
    if (!_rtcEngine) {
        _rtcEngine = vi::RTCEngineFactory::createEngine();
        _rtcEngine->init();
    }
}

namespace vi {
    std::shared_ptr<IRTCEngine> RTCEngineFactory::createEngine()
    {
        return RTCEngine::instance();
    }
}
```

And here header for the class itself which wrapped by AppDelegate

```
namespace vi {
    class RTCEngine 
        : public IRTCEngine
        , public ISignalingClientObserver
        , public Observable
        , public std::enable_shared_from_this<RTCEngine>
    {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<IRTCEngine> instance()
        {
            static std::shared_ptr<IRTCEngine> _instance;
            static std::once_flag ocf;
            std::call_once(ocf, []() {
                _instance.reset(new RTCEngine());
            });
            return _instance;
        }

        ~RTCEngine() override;

        void init() override;

        void destroy() override;

        void registerEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<IEngineEventHandler> handler) override;

        void unregisterEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<IEngineEventHandler> handler) override;

        void setOptions(const Options& opts) override;

        void startup() override;

        void shutdown() override;

        std::shared_ptr<VideoRoomClientInterface> createVideoRoomClient() override;

        std::shared_ptr<IUnifiedFactory> getUnifiedFactory();

    protected:
        void onSessionStatus(SessionStatus status) override;

    private:
        RTCEngine();

        RTCEngine(const RTCEngine&) = delete;

        RTCEngine& operator=(const RTCEngine&) = delete;

    private:
        friend class Singleton<RTCEngine>;

        std::shared_ptr<IUnifiedFactory> _unifiedFactory;

        std::vector<std::weak_ptr<IEngineEventHandler>> _observers;

        Options _options;

        rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface> _pcf;
        std::unique_ptr<rtc::Thread> _signaling;
        std::unique_ptr<rtc::Thread> _worker;
        std::unique_ptr<rtc::Thread> _network;
    };

}
```

Here is the init method body

```
void RTCEngine::init()
    {
        if (!_pcf) {
            _signaling = rtc::Thread::Create();
            _signaling->SetName("pc_signaling_thread", nullptr);
            _signaling->Start();
            _worker = rtc::Thread::Create();
            _worker->SetName("pc_worker_thread", nullptr);
            _worker->Start();
            _network = rtc::Thread::CreateWithSocketServer();
            _network->SetName("pc_network_thread", nullptr);
            _network->Start();
            _pcf = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(
                _network.get() /* network_thread */,
                _worker.get() /* worker_thread */,
                _signaling.get() /* signaling_thread */,
                nullptr /* default_adm */,
                webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioEncoderFactory(),
                webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioDecoderFactory(),
                webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoEncoderFactory(),
                webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoDecoderFactory(),
                nullptr /* audio_mixer */,
                nullptr /* audio_processing */);
        }

        _unifiedFactory = std::make_shared<UnifiedFactory>();
        _unifiedFactory->init();

        _unifiedFactory->getSignalingClient()->registerObserver(shared_from_this());
    }

void UnifiedFactory::init()
    {
        if (!_threadProvider) {
            _threadProvider = std::make_unique<vi::ThreadProvider>();
            _threadProvider->init();
            _threadProvider->create({ "signaling-service", "plugin-client", "message-transport", "capture-session" });
        }

        if (!_serviceFactory) {
            _serviceFactory = std::make_shared<vi::ServiceFactory>();
            _serviceFactory->init();
        }

        if (!_signalingClient) {
            _signalingClient = vi::SignalingClientProxy::Create(_threadProvider->thread("signaling-service"), std::make_shared<vi::SignalingClient>());
            _signalingClient->init();
        }
    }
```

This part is for thread provider, thread provider is the set of treads associated with it's name for correct execution of functions for call back in observers, I don't know why it's wrap current thread, why need to do like that and not just add threads into container and just start them.

With code of
_signalingClient = vi::SignalingClientProxy::Create(_threadProvider->thread("signaling-service"), std::make_shared<vi::SignalingClient>());
signaling client has to be run with signaling-service thread.

Header of class thread manager,and add and find methods ,see below. It's just manage created threads

```
class ThreadProvider
    {
    public:
        ThreadProvider();

        ~ThreadProvider();

        void init();

        void destroy();

        void create(const std::list<std::string>& threadNames);

        rtc::Thread* thread(const std::string& name);

    private:
        ThreadProvider(const ThreadProvider&) = delete;

        ThreadProvider(ThreadProvider&&) = delete;

        ThreadProvider& operator=(const ThreadProvider&) = delete;

    public:
        void stopAll();

    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<rtc::Thread>> _threadsMap;
        
        std::mutex _mutex;

        rtc::Thread* _mainThread = nullptr;

        std::atomic_bool _inited;

        std::atomic_bool _destroy;
    };





void ThreadProvider::init()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        _mainThread = rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->CurrentThread();

        _inited = true;
    }

    void ThreadProvider::destroy()
    {
        _destroy = true;
    }

    void ThreadProvider::create(const std::list<std::string>& threadNames)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        if (!_inited) {
            DLOG("_inited == false");
            return;
        }

        for (const auto& name : threadNames) {
            _threadsMap[name] = rtc::Thread::Create();
            _threadsMap[name]->SetName(name, nullptr);
            _threadsMap[name]->Start();
        }
    }
```

Here is passing through observers with threads itself, it found interesting observer, but when it have execute thread and call callback it the thread remained in the queue and did not execute, as if it had not been notified for execution.

```
template<typename Observer>
    class UniversalObservable {
    public:
        using observer_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Observer>;
        void addWeakObserver(const observer_ptr &observer, absl::optional<std::string> threadName) {
            rtc::CritScope scope(&_criticalSection);
            if (!hasObserverInternal(observer)) {
                WeakObject wobj(observer, threadName);
                _observers.emplace_back(wobj);
            }
        }
        
        void addObserver(const observer_ptr &observer, absl::optional<std::string> threadName) {
            rtc::CritScope scope(&_criticalSection);
            if (!hasObserverInternal(observer)) {
                Object obj(observer, threadName);
                _observers.emplace_back(obj);
            }
        }
        

virtual void notifyObservers(std::function<void(const observer_ptr &)> notifier) const {
        decltype(_observers) observers;
        {
            rtc::CritScope scope(&_criticalSection);
            observers = _observers;
        }
        
        for (const auto &observer: observers) {
            auto var = absl::any(observer);
            if (var.has_value()) {
                std::shared_ptr<Observer> obs;
                absl::optional<std::string> threadName;
                
                if (absl::any_cast<WeakObject>(&var)) {
                    WeakObject wobj = absl::any_cast<WeakObject>(var);
                    obs = wobj.observer.lock();
                    threadName = wobj.threadName;
                } else if (absl::any_cast<Object>(&var)) {
                    Object obj = absl::any_cast<Object>(var);
                    obs = obj.observer;
                    threadName = obj.threadName;
                }
                
                if (obs) {
                    rtc::Thread* thread = TMgr->thread(threadName.value_or(""));
                    assert(thread);
                    if (thread->IsCurrent()) {
                        notifier(obs);
                    }
                    else {
                        //notifier(obs);
                        thread->PostTask(RTC_FROM_HERE, [wobs = std::weak_ptr<Observer>(obs), notifier]() {
                            if (auto observer = wobs.lock()) {
                                notifier(observer);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after that initialization, called lines below, I'm not discussing about elements between and behind, it's logic is independent for that problem.

auto jcDialog = std::make_shared(nullptr);
jcDialog->init();

```
JanusConnectionDialog header, it inherited from handler interface so it could work as observer.

class JanusConnectionDialog : public QDialog, public vi::IEngineEventHandler, public std::enable_shared_from_this<JanusConnectionDialog>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    JanusConnectionDialog(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    ~JanusConnectionDialog();

    void init();

    void cleanup();

private slots:
    void on_connectJanusPushButton_clicked();

    void on_cancelConnectPushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:

    // IEngineEventHandler

    void onStatus(vi::EngineStatus status) override;

    void onError(int32_t code) override;

private:
    Ui::JanusConnectionDialog ui;
};



void JanusConnectionDialog::init()
{
    appDelegate->getRtcEngine()->registerEventHandler(shared_from_this());
}
```

And register Event handler itself, which add observer to list of observers

```
void RTCEngine::registerEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<IEngineEventHandler> handler)
    {
        Observable::addBizObserver<IEngineEventHandler>(_observers, handler);
    }
```

After I push button to connect to server, meessage after succesed connection have to be returned to slot, it's not qt slot , just my function for get messages from registerEventHandler, it's not called if I comment first four lines

```
rtc::WinsockInitializer winsockInit;
rtc::Win32SocketServer w32ss;
rtc::Win32Thread w32Thread(&w32ss);
rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->SetCurrentThread(&w32Thread);
```

,
but it work correct with windows
The observer call back is

```
void RTCEngine::onSessionStatus(SessionStatus status)
    {
        Observable::notifyObserver4Change<IEngineEventHandler>(_observers, [status](const auto& observer) {
            EngineStatus es = status == SessionStatus::CONNECTED ? EngineStatus::CONNECTED : EngineStatus::DISCONNECTED;
            observer->onStatus(es);
        });
    }
```

Which call onStatus, for signaling, that , there is opened connection

```
void JanusConnectionDialog::onStatus(vi::EngineStatus status)
{
    if (vi::EngineStatus::CONNECTED == status) {
        accept();
    }
}
```

And here is the code for calling an observer call back, this callback is called always, because I have a notification about channel is open and json message is pass through that method, but there is no observer notification in lambda, after executing notifyobservers.
See upper, code with class UniversalObservable::notifyobservers

```
void SignalingClient::createSession(std::shared_ptr<CreateSessionEvent> event)
    {
        auto lambda = [wself = weak_from_this(), event](const std::string& json) {
            std::string err;
            std::shared_ptr<CreateSessionResponse> model = fromJsonString<CreateSessionResponse>(json, err);
            if (!err.empty()) {
                DLOG("parse JanusResponse failed");
                return;
            }

            DLOG("model.janus = {}", model->janus.value_or(""));
            if (auto self = wself.lock()) {
                self->_sessionId = model->session_id.value_or(0) > 0 ? model->session_id.value() : model->data->id.value();
                self->startHeartbeat();
                self->_sessionStatus =SessionStatus::CONNECTED;

                
self->UniversalObservable<ISignalingClientObserver>::notifyObservers([](const auto& observer) {
//here is the part for calling an observer and return call back
                    observer->onSessionStatus(SessionStatus::CONNECTED);
                });

                if (event && event->callback) {
                    self->_eventHandlerThread->PostTask(RTC_FROM_HERE, [cb = event->callback]() {
                        (*cb)(true, "");
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        std::shared_ptr<JCCallback> callback = std::make_shared<JCCallback>(lambda);
        if (event && event->reconnect) {
            _client->reconnectSession(_sessionId, callback);
        }
        else {
            _client->createSession(callback);
        }
    }
```

This method, is where this call back has to be executed, but it never called

```
void RTCEngine::onSessionStatus(SessionStatus status)
    {
        Observable::notifyObserver4Change<IEngineEventHandler>(_observers, [status](const auto& observer) {
            EngineStatus es = status == SessionStatus::CONNECTED ? EngineStatus::CONNECTED : EngineStatus::DISCONNECTED;
            observer->onStatus(es);
        });
    }
```

Maybe there is some mechanisms to work with linux system as windows, or some example which do the same functionality as this four lines, it's work under windows, so it could be some hidden calls for passing a message up to client application from library.

```
rtc::WinsockInitializer winsockInit;
rtc::Win32SocketServer w32ss;
rtc::Win32Thread w32Thread(&w32ss);
rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->SetCurrentThread(&w32Thread);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So I found, not a resolving, but avoidance. And it work correct for now, maybe it would cost me another problems, for solving it.

So, the main idea was to wrap main thread with std::thread, so after  that messages are passing through,

```
#include "ui.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "rtc_base/checks.h"
#include "rtc_base/ssl_adapter.h"

#include "rtc_base/physical_socket_server.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <memory>
#include "service/rtc_engine.h"
#include "signaling_client_interface.h"
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

#include "api/media_stream_interface.h"
#include "api/create_peerconnection_factory.h"
#include "api/video_codecs/builtin_video_decoder_factory.h"
#include "api/video_codecs/builtin_video_encoder_factory.h"
#include "api/audio_codecs/builtin_audio_decoder_factory.h"
#include "api/audio_codecs/builtin_audio_encoder_factory.h"
#include "modules/audio_device/include/audio_device.h"
#include "modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h"
#include "modules/video_capture/video_capture_factory.h"
#include "pc/video_track_source.h"
#include "video_capture.h"
#include "gl_video_renderer.h"
#include "participant.h"
#include "api/media_stream_interface.h"
#include "janus_connection_dialog.h"
//#include "rtc_base/win32_socket_init.h"
#include "rtc_base/physical_socket_server.h"
#include "logger/logger.h"
#include "app_delegate.h"

static void registerMetaTypes()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<std::function<void()>>("std::function<void()>");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<std::string>>("std::vector<std::string>");

    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("int64_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("uint64_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("int32_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<uint64_t>("uint32_t");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<vi::Participant>>("std::shared_ptr<vi::Participant>");
    qRegisterMetaType<rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::MediaStreamInterface>>("rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackInterface>");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<vi::CreateRoomResult>>("std::shared_ptr<vi::CreateRoomResult>");
}

static void initOpenGL() {
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(3, 2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
}


class CustomSocketServer : public rtc::PhysicalSocketServer {
 public:
  explicit CustomSocketServer() {}
  virtual ~CustomSocketServer() {}

  void SetMessageQueue(rtc::Thread* queue) override { message_queue_ = queue; }

 
  bool Wait(int cms, bool process_io) override {
  
    return rtc::PhysicalSocketServer::Wait(1 /*cms == -1 ? 1 : cms*/,
                                           process_io);
  }

  void WakeUp() override {
        std::cout<<"Called wake up for CustomSocket server"<<std::endl;
        rtc::PhysicalSocketServer::WakeUp();
  }

 protected:
  rtc::Thread* message_queue_;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vi::Logger::init();

    CustomSocketServer socket_server;

    rtc::AutoSocketServerThread threadPosix(&socket_server);

    appDelegate->init();

    registerMetaTypes();

    rtc::InitializeSSL();

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    initOpenGL();

    int ret = 0;

    /*Use it, as wrap to thread, because threadPosix is blocking*/
    std::thread mainThread = std::thread([&threadPosix](){
        threadPosix.Start();
    });

    auto jcDialog = std::make_shared<JanusConnectionDialog>(nullptr);
    jcDialog->init();

    if (QDialog::Accepted == jcDialog->exec()) {
        jcDialog->cleanup();

        std::shared_ptr<GUI> w = std::make_shared<GUI>();
        appDelegate->getRtcEngine()->registerEventHandler(w);

        w->show();

        w->init();

        ret = a.exec();
    }

    appDelegate->destroy();

    
    if(mainThread.joinable())
        mainThread.join();

    rtc::CleanupSSL();

    return ret;
}
```

And setting message to thread through method described below, It select a thread called main.

```
 if (obs) {
                    rtc::Thread* thread = TMgr->thread(threadName.value_or(""));
                    assert(thread);
                    if (thread->IsCurrent()) {
                        notifier(obs);
                    }
                    else {
                        //notifier(obs);
                        thread->PostTask(RTC_FROM_HERE, [wobs = std::weak_ptr<Observer>(obs), notifier]() {
                            if (auto observer = wobs.lock()) {
                                notifier(observer);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

In lines below, are initialization of thread, called main:

```
void ThreadProvider::init()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        _mainThread = rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->CurrentThread();

        _inited = true;
    }
```

So, as first, registered main thread, after, wrap std::thread around
webrtc::thread, for resolving problem of blocking, and returning data, it worked.

As a reference I used this article:
https://blog.brkho.com/2017/03/15/dive-into-client-server-web-games-webrtc/

I would be glad for any comments for my technical solvation.